# how can i install Gprof on Ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, gprof

i want to use Gprofiler and I have Ubuntu on virtual Box.

run following command:
$ gprof
$ a.out: No such file or directory

$ apt-get install binutils

but when i run gprof , i have this error again
$ a.out: No such file or directoryn

Comment: Drop the `$` is the filename? So it's plain `a.out`. Or, if you named your executable using e.g. the `-o` option use that filename?

Comment: Also if you want to do GPU profiling, then [`gprof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) is not the command to use. [This link should hopefully help you](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/463841/using-gprof-with-cuda-can-this-profiler-be-used-with-liunx-c-and-cuda-/).

Comment: that link doesn't exist

Comment: That's weird, I can go to both links just fine. And the second link in my comment is the first hit I get when searching for `gprof gpu profiling`. The articel is called "Using gprof with CUDA Can this profiler be used with liunx c and CUDA?" (which you can search for too).